# What does $\mathcal{J}$ stand for in Green relations?

Tags: abstract-algebra, semigroups

Following this book [The Algebraic Theory of Semigroups, Volume I](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0821802712) , we see that:

- $a\mathcal{L}b$ means $a$ and $b$ generate the same principle **left** ideal of the semigroup $S$.
- $a\mathcal{R}b$ means $a$ and $b$ generate the same principle **right** ideal of the semigroup $S$.
- $\mathcal{D}$ is denoted for the **join** of the equivalence relations $\mathcal{L}$ and $\mathcal{R}$.
- $\mathcal{H}$ is denoted for the **intersection** of the equivalence relations $\mathcal{L}$ and $\mathcal{R}$ and,
- $a\mathcal{J}b$ means that $$S^1aS^1=S^1bS^1$$

I am asking if there is a name for the last equivalence relation as we have for other four relations. In fact, I am looking for a **bold** version for the last one. Thanks so much for your hints and the time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is:

$a\mathcal{J}b$ means that $a$ and $b$ generate the same principal **2-sided** ideal of the semigroup $S$.

For finite, or more generally periodic semigroups, $\mathcal{D}=\mathcal{J}$.

Comment: Thanks James for your kind suggestion. May I ask more?

Comment: Please feel free to ask more.

Comment: Thanks for letting me to ask some points: **1.** Which one is better while someone works on finitely generated semigroup, `relation` or `relator`? I mean, if `S=<X|R>` so, is it OK to call `R` the set of realtors? Or you think, it's better call it the set of relations exactly as we do for groups? **2.** I have searched the web to find a proper code in GAP in which I can examine the dual of a finite semigroup. I just found `IsSelfDualSemigroup` under the `smallsemi` package.

Comment: Are any other codes in which I could find the dual semigroup? Thanks so much. If you prefer the last question as an independent question please tell me to do that on the site. Thanks again. :-)

Answer (score 2):

It's perhaps worth noting that $\mathcal{J}$ can also be described in terms of joins/**compositions** $\mathcal{X}\circ\mathcal{Y}$, where $a(\mathcal{X}\circ\mathcal{Y})b\Leftrightarrow\exists c\in S(a\mathcal{X}c\mathcal{Y}b)$.  Indeed, if we assume $S=S^1$ and consider the relations
\begin{align*}
a\leq_\mathcal{L}b&\quad\Leftrightarrow\quad Sa\subseteq Sb\qquad\text{and}\\
a\leq_\mathcal{R}b&\quad\Leftrightarrow\quad aS\subseteq bS
\end{align*}
then the only difference between $\mathcal{D}$ and $\mathcal{J}$ is the order in which we take compositions and **symmetrizations** $\mathcal{X}^\mathrm{sym}=\mathcal{X}\cap\mathcal{X}^{-1}$, where $a\mathcal{X}^{-1}b\Leftrightarrow b\mathcal{X}a$.  Specifically,
\begin{align*}
\mathcal{L}&=\leq_\mathcal{L}^\mathrm{sym},\\
\mathcal{R}&=\leq_\mathcal{R}^\mathrm{sym},\\
\mathcal{D}&=\leq_\mathcal{L}^\mathrm{sym}\circ\leq_\mathcal{R}^\mathrm{sym}\quad\text{and}\\
\mathcal{J}&=(\leq_\mathcal{L}\circ\leq_\mathcal{R})^\mathrm{sym}.
\end{align*}

Comment: Thanks for the answer!